# MyCompany lsfusion проблема с импортом

Tags: lsfusion

Всем Здравствуйте! Установил My Company в учебных целях. Хочу сделать учебный проект в университете. Возникла проблема с импортом данных, т.к. нет желания вводить все справочники вручную. На сайте с документацией ссылки на формы импорта не открываются. Я попробовал выгрузить с демоверсии, логично предположив (а может и нет) что экспорт будет в том же формате что и импорт. При попытке например импортировать справочник стран выдаёт ошибку ниже. В документации и google инфы не нашёл. Так и не понял проблема в самом excel файле? или в коде импорта? Буду благодарен за совет! Заранее Спасибо! [image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Попробуйте в ссылке, которая не открывается, убрать слэш в конце

Answer (score 1):

Код импорта стран находится в модуле CountryImport : https://github.com/lsfusion-solutions/mycompany/blob/master/src/main/lsfusion/masterdata/countries/CountryImport.lsf

Код действия, которое непосредственно осуществляет импорт :

```
countryImport 'Import countries' () {
    LOCAL id = STRING[3] (INTEGER);
    LOCAL name = ISTRING[50] (INTEGER);
    LOCAL alpha2 = ISTRING[2] (INTEGER);
    LOCAL alpha3 = ISTRING[3] (INTEGER);
    
    INPUT f = EXCELFILE DO {
        NEWSESSION {
            IMPORT XLS HEADER FROM f TO id = A, name = B, alpha2 = C, alpha3 = D;
            
            FOR imported(INTEGER i) NEW im = Country DO {
                id(im) <- id(i);
                name(im) <- name(i);
                alpha2(im) <- alpha2(i);
                alpha3(im) <- alpha3(i);
            }
            APPLY;
            MESSAGE 'Import completed';
        }
    }    
}
```

В импортируемом файле код берется из первой колонки (A), а наименование из второй (B).

Ошибка на скрине - это срабатывание ограничения, что не задан код. При этом видно, что наименования на скрине (008, 010, 051 и т.д.) - это, скорее всего, коды. Таким образом, в импортируемом файле, наиболее вероятно, идет смещение колонок, и код идет во второй колонке. То есть проблема возможно в файле.

Экспорт действительно идет в том же параметре, что и импорт. И там код в первой колонке :

[image: Экспорт стран]

Comment: у меня экспорт файл выглядит немного иначе, попробую сделать по вашему примеру.

Comment: Да вы правы, в экспортируемом файле который я получил выгрузив справочник стран из демо версии, Код страны идёт по 2 колонке. первая остаётся пустой. При сдвиге колонки с id влево ( в первую колонку)  просто выдаёт ошибку (внутренняя ошибка сервера).

Comment: Обычно при внутренней ошибке сервера есть 2 стека. LSF стэк и Java стэк. Хорошо бы их тоже иметь, чтобы определить суть проблемы.